# Save-AzureVMImage Generalized vs. Specialized

Tags: azure, iaas

I've looked extensively at the Azure documentation regarding saving VM images. I understand there are two types available, Generalized and Specialized. I've read explanations of what the differences are. However, these appear to be written mostly for those very familiar with Azure concepts or IT in general. I'm more on the development side.

To my problem... I have an azure hosted image, which i've used as a build agent for teamcity. Our application isn't vanilla in that we can just install Visual Studio and be done. (i wish). We have about 20 or so third party dependent applications to install to the main OS disk, with lots of configuration required (System variables, etc.) to get it all to work.

So finally to my question - Which is the right version to use? Specialized or Generalized? I want to spawn 4 copies of this server in the same cloud service.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generalized since you want them to be in the same cloud service. Generalized images start up differently as they configure themselves to take on new identities during their first start up.